# Facebook iPhone SDK Authorization question

Tags: iphone, facebook

I want users to be able to log on to my iPhone app, with their facebook credentials, WITHOUT displaying Facebook's login screen. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

you cant, the point of the screen is that you dont get a handle on the users username and password...If there wasnt a screen and you actually entered the username and password to some login call, then you can just have the app send you the credentials and you are free to use them as you please..